# Pointers to the same array in Java

Tags: java, pointers

I just want to make sure I'm clear on this, as I'm not quite sure of the exact behavior. I have two arrays:

```
private short[] bufferA;
private short[] bufferB;
```

which I want to swap between. Can I do something like this:

```
private short[] currentBuffer;

while(something)
  {
  currentBuffer = (condition) ? bufferA : bufferB;
  modify(currentBuffer);
  }
```

to modify the bufferA or bufferB depending on some condition, or should I use flags and manually code it like this:

```
private int currentBuffer;

while(something){
  currentBuffer = (condition) ? BUFFER_A : BUFFER_B;
  if(currentBuffer == BUFFER_A) {
    modify(bufferA);
  }else{
    modify(bufferB);
  }
}
```

The code I'm working with is more complex than this simplified example, so if I can do it the first way that would be much preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although your arrays are holding primitives, Arrays itself are objects

- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#12028

so reference works ok.

Java passes by value primitives, and by reference objects.

Udo

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. References to arrays are like any other references.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first way will work just fine with arrays (or any other containers).

However, you can not reassign variables, just change their contents:

```
int myVar = someCondition ? myInt1 : myInt2;
// this has no effect on either myInt1 or myInt2
myVar = 1000;
```

The reason here is that Java passes everything by value, including references.

So if you pass a reference to a container somewhere else, that code can change the container's content and your code will see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Both are allrite.. you can go ahead with the 1st way..
**EDIT:** as a side note, references in java are more like pointers in c++ than references in c++. course there still are some differences between java references and c++ pointers e.g. u can do pointer arithmetic in c++..